# Extracting data from a collection in Java

Tags: java, linq, csv

I have a csv dataset like this:

```
A, 10, USA
B,30, UK
C,4,IT
A,20,UK
B,10,USA
```

I want to read this csv lines and provide the following output:

```
A has ran 30 miles with average of 15. 
B has ran 30 miles with average of 20.
C has ran 4 miles with average of 4.
```

I want to achieve this in Java. I have done this in C# by using Linq:

```
var readlines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
            var query = from lines in readlines
                        let data = lines.Split(',')
                        select new
                        {
                            Name = data[0],
                            Miles = data[1],

                        };

            var values = query.GroupBy(x => new {x.Name}).Select(group => new { Person = group.Key, Events = group.Sum(g =>Convert.ToDouble(g.Miles)) ,Count = group.Count() });
```

I am looking to do this in Java, and I am not sure if I can do this without using any third party library or not? Any ideas?
So far, my code looks like this in Java:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filename));
        java.util.List<String[]> content = reader.readAll();
        String[] row = null;
        for(Object object:content)
        {
          row = (String[]) object;
          String Name = row[0];
          String Miles = row[1];



          System.out.printf("%s has ran %s miles %n",Name,Miles);
        }

           reader.close();  
        }
```

I am looking for a nice way to get the total milage value for each name to calculate for the average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a C# developer, it is hard sometimes not to miss the features of linq. But as Farlan suggested you could do something like this:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filename));
    java.util.List<String[]> content = reader.readAll();
    Map<String, Group> groups = new HashMap<>();
    for(String[] row : content)
    {
        String Name = row[0];
        String Miles = row[1];

        System.out.printf("%s has ran %s miles %n", Name, Miles);

        if (groups.containsKey(Name)){
            groups.get(Name).Add(Double.valueOf(Miles));
        } else {
            Group g = new Group();
            g.Add(Double.valueOf(Miles));
            groups.put(Name, g);
        }
    }
    reader.close();

    for (String name : groups.keySet())
    {
        System.out.println(name + " ran " + groups.get(name).total() + " with avg of " + groups.get(name).average());
    }


}

class Group {
    private List<Double> miles;

    public Group()
    {
        miles = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Double total(){
        double sum = 0;
        for (Double mile : miles)
        {
            sum += mile;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public Double average(){
        if (miles.size() == 0)
            return 0d;            
        return total() / miles.size();
    }

    public void Add(Double m){
        miles.add(m);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you compile this? how can you have ArrayList<>() in your constructor and List<Double> as your property?

Comment: I fixed this code, and this code has to be written slightly differently for Java 1.6 and Java 1.7. this code gave me another great reason to love C#.

Comment: You didn't specify a version in your tags, so i just assumed 1.7. Fill in the missing types for 1.6 :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Java's BufferedReader class:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("your.csv"));
String line;
while ( (line = in.readLine()) != null) {
  String [] fields = line.split(",");
  System.out.println(fields[0] + " has ran " + fields[1] + " miles with average " + fields[2]);
}
```

Comment: The problem is not parsing the data, I have already done that nicely with open-csv. To find the average, I have to group the data around the Name field and find the miles and add them up and divide by how many times the Name field is repeated to get the average. That is what the C# code does, and I am looking for a concise solution like that in Java.

Comment: Then use a HashMap with the key as name and the value as the number.

Comment: ok, I implemented that, but how do you group the data around a value, like how can I group the milage around the name value?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to do this, some long-winded approaches, some shorter. The issue is that Java can be very verbose for doing simple tasks, so the better approaches can be a bit uglier.

The example below shows you exactly how to achieve this, par the printing. Bear in mind however, it might not be the best approach but I feel its more of the easier ones to read and comprehend.

```
    final File csvFile = new File("filename.csv");
    final Scanner reader = new Scanner(csvFile);
    
    final Map<String, Integer> info = new HashMap<>(); //Store the data
    
    //Until there is are no more lines, continue
    while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
        final String[] data = reader.nextLine().split(","); // data[0] = A. [1] = 10. [2] = USA
        final String alpha = data[0];
        
        if (!info.containsKey(alpha)) {
            info.put(alpha, Integer.parseInt(data[1]));
        } else {
            int miles = info.get(alpha);
            info.put(alpha, miles + Integer.parseInt(data[1]));
        }
    }
    
    reader.close();
```

The steps involved are simple:

#### Step 1 - Read the file.

By passing a `File` into the `Scanner` object, you set the target parsing to the `File` and not the console. Using the very neat `hasNextLine()` method, you can continually read each line until no more exist. Each line is then split by a comma, and stored in a String array for reference.

#### Step 2 - Associating the data.

As you want to cumulatively add the integers together, you need a way to associate already passed in letters with the numbers. A heavyweight but clean way of doing this is to use a `HashMap`. The `Key` which it takes is going to be a String, specifically `A` `B` or `C`. By taking advantage of the fact the `Key` is unique, we can use the `O(1)` `containsKey(String)` method to check if we've already read in the letter. If its new, add it to the `HashMap` and save the number with it. *If* however, the letter has been seen before, we find the old value, add it with the new one and overwrite the data inside the `HashMap`.

All you need to do now is print out the data. Feel free to take a different approach, but I hope this is a clear example of how you *CAN* do it in Java.

Comment: Thank you for your try, but I am wondering what good this solution does to me? the code that I have written up there already does what your code does in a very simple and nice way. The problem is not parsing, the problem is to add the miles, calculate for them and print them for each runner, A, B,...

Comment: But your code doesn't add up the miles, the code I gave does. All you need to do is print out the data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this Java library: https://code.google.com/p/qood/

It handles data without any getter/setters, so it's more flexible than LINQ.

in your case, file "D:/input.csv" has 3 columns:

```
NAME,MILES,COUNTRY
A, 10, USA
B,30, UK
C,4,IT
A,20,UK
B,10,USA
```

the query code would be:

```
final QModel raw = QNew.modelCSV("D:/input.csv")
  .debug(-1);//print out what read from CSV
raw.query()
  .selectAs("OUTPUT", 
    "CONCAT(NAME,' has ran ',SUM(MILES),' miles with average of ',MEAN(MILES),'.')")
  .groupBy("NAME")
  .result().debug(-1)//print out the result
  .to().fileCSV("D:/output.csv", "UTF-8");//write to another CSV file
```